# Edit in Excel Web App,dropdown with formula disabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, excel

After uploading the tracker in SharePoint,I want  all the formulas including the data validation and dependent drop down are still available when we edit the workbook through "`Edit in Excel Web App`".

When I tried to update via web app, the drop down is disabled. Is the functionality not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this functionality is not yet supported in o365 yet. So data validation doesn't work.